# Inform 7 [the noun] in description of location

Tags: inform7

I'm trying to put "stranger man" instead [the noun]. In this piece of code:

> Rule for listing nondescript items: do nothing.

```
A staircase is a kind of door. A staircase is usually open.
A staircase is seldom openable. The ladder is a staircase. 
The ladder is above the Entry and below the Reception. 
The description of Entry is "You see ladder forward.".
A stranger man is man in the Reception. 
The description of Reception is "You see [the noun] at the reception. On the left side is corridor.".
```

In describing the location, I see "the up" instead of "the stranger man". But after attack and `remove the noun from play;`, I see "nothing" - all right.

```
Entry
You see ladder forward.

>up

Reception
You see the up at the reception. On the left side is corridor.

>attack man
You attack the stranger man, causing 5 points of damage!

The stranger man attacks you, causing 7 points of damage!

>attack man
You attack the stranger man, causing 8 points of damage!

The stranger man attacks you, causing 7 points of damage!

>attack man
You attack the stranger man, causing 6 points of damage!

The stranger man attacks you, causing 2 points of damage!

>attack man
You attack the stranger man, causing 4 points of damage!

The stranger man attacks you, causing 8 points of damage!

>attack man
You attack the stranger man, causing 10 points of damage!

The stranger man die, you win!

>attack man
You can't see any such thing.

>look
Reception
You see nothing at the reception. On the left side is corridor.
```

why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"The noun" is a global variable referring to whatever the main object of the previous action was, which in this case is the direction "up". When you looked the second time, it tries to access the previous object, but because the parser failed the result is the null object, "nothing".

I'm not too sure what you're trying to do, but trying to refer to a man who won't always be there in the room description like that is almost certainly the wrong approach. If what you're trying to do is to list the man before the exits, then the Room Description Control by Emily Short extension might help.

Comment: But how do I create a generic reference to the characters that I can remove from the game?

Comment: @user3091874 I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: I need to remove the character from the game and all of his mention in the description of the room.

Comment: Well then just don't mention him manually in the room description - the library will handle describing him when he's present.

Comment: I disabled it. (Rule for listing nondescript items: do nothing.)
Because I wanted to things or people they were part of the description. And not to mention after the description. Like here:
<pre>
You see reception. On the left side is corridor.

You can see a ladder and a stranger man here.
</pre>
Because I do not want to mention about ladder. Only about stranger man.

Comment: The simpler way is to just make the ladder scenery. And if you really want to mention the man in the room description then use an if phrase.